# What would armor designed to withstand a grenade blast in an enclosed space look like?

Tags: engineering, military, armors, military-defense, explosions

Let's say that someone throws an [M67 hand grenade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M67_grenade) into a completely enclosed room - i.e. the door is the only entrance/exit.

How would someone build a suit of armor to functionally negate the following factors?

- thermal effects of the grenade blast
- the [alveoli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulmonary_alveolus)-[destroying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulmonary_contusion) shockwave caused by 180 grams of [Composition B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_B) explosive going off
- the shrapnel the grenade launches

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like an [atmospheric driving suit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_diving_suit) or ADS, as shown below, might not be perfect but it would certainly be a good place to start. The M67 is actually designed for minimal thermal output so the shock and overpressure are the hardest to mitigate, if a suit of armour can take those then the steel fragments (which are not actually shrapnel apparently) and flame are relatively minor. The fragments may cause minor dents in an ADS but the suit is designed to take 900psi, plus safe margin. Modern suits have 6 hours of sealed operational life support but if working in atmosphere a good engineer should be able to rig an exchange system to use outside air to extend that indefinitely without a direct link that would render the suit sensitive to overpressure.

[image]

Comment: Question: the suit is designed against high pressure, but does it protect against *sudden* high pressures?

Comment: @Demigan EOD plus diving suit = perfect combo

Comment: @Demigan They're designed to protect the diver from changes in pressure caused by a tether line snapping and them falling to working depth, not quite the quick shock of an explosion I'll grant but still a rapid change in pressure.

Comment: Based on the image provided, they would appear to rely on the curvature of the surface to support that 900psi.  Receiving "minor dents" would almost certainly cause a significant reduction in pressure rating.  I have no prior knowledge of these suits, so my feedback is only based on engineering common sense; YMMV.

Comment: @IanWizard Almost certainly, I would not expect such a suit to keep it's rating after exposure to a blast any more than an EOD suit is reused after being at ground zero without being refurbished or it is advisable to reuse a bulletproof vest that has been hit before without changing out the fibre panels.

Comment: @Ash Good point.  I also realize that I was imagining the suit being actively used in a high-pressure environment, which is entirely *not* the context of the question.  It seems my brain made assumptions without me realizing it.

Answer (score 7):

Just an EOD suit, perhaps with a closed off helmet?

[image: just an EOD suit]

EOD suits are made of thick material to both absorb a blast and catch shrapnel. They are specifically designed it, I dont see much you can do but add extra layers.